# Preserving DTI ratio between mortgage pre-approval and closing

Tags: united-states, mortgage, credit-score

I am in the process of buying a house in the US. I have had an offer accepted and have pre-approval from a lender for a conventional/conforming loan at the maximum debt to income (DTI) that they are wiling to underwrite (I think it is 49%). While the DTI is very high, I will be able to comfortably afford the payments as my wife will start working about a month after closing on the house and our combined DTI will be reasonable.

We are US citizens currently living in the UK. I have excellent credit (780+) in the US and a bunch of credit cards that I have not used in over 5 years. I will be living in the US for about a month prior to closing on the house. I want to avoid doing anything that will impact my DTI (or credit score) during that month.

I can live on cash taken from my UK bank and gifts from friends and family for the month, which will not show up on my US credit report, but I would rather be able to use my US ATM card, debit card, and credit cards. I would also like to get a cell phone and monthly bus pass, but not at the cost of losing/decreasing my loan. Are there other things I should avoid

Comment: that month will appear on your credit score a couple of months later